# SQL query - get a featured image's alt / alternative text

Tags: post-meta, query, sql

I am writing some SQL queries to get post data out of a database for certain posts (so WP functions are not an option). I am trying to get post IDs, post URLs, post featured image URLs and associated alt text for the featured images. Alt text is held in the postmeta table with the meta_key '_wp_attachment_image_alt'.

The query below works for everything **except alt text**. I am confident I need to use a left join because I want all posts returned regardless of whether they have featured images. My query however is returning null values for alt text for images I have confirmed have alt text.

```sql
SELECT 
    wp_posts.id as "Post ID",
    wp_posts.guid as "Post URL",
    (SELECT wp_posts.id
        FROM   wp_posts
        WHERE  wp_posts.id = pm13.meta_value) AS "Featured Image ID",
    
    (SELECT wp_posts.guid
        FROM   wp_posts
        WHERE  wp_posts.id = pm13.meta_value) AS "Featured Image URL",
    
    (SELECT pm14.meta_value
        FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE  wp_posts.id = pm14.meta_value
        ) as "Featured Image Alt Text"

    FROM   wp_posts
    
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm13
        ON (
            pm13.post_id = wp_posts.ID  AND
            pm13.meta_key    = '_thumbnail_id'
        )

    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm14
        ON (
            pm14.post_id = wp_posts.ID  AND
            pm14.meta_key    = '_wp_attachment_image_alt'
        )
    
    WHERE  wp_posts.post_status = "publish"
           AND wp_posts.post_type = "post"
    
    
    ORDER  BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Comment: can you add some context for using raw SQL? Do you have direct access to make HTTP requests? Note that the images are of type `attachment` and it can be possible for an image to have one alt value, but for a different alt value to appear in the post content. Likewise it's possible for there to be no alt value at all, or for a plugin to override it. I would also note that such an SQL query bypasses all the caching that `WP_Query` performs, as well as object caches and plugin filters

Comment: I am migrating data out of the DB to a different CMS, so SQL is really the only option.

Comment: that's not true, you can do this in code from PHP, or via REST API requests, or using multiple SQL queries, it doesn't have to be done as a single all encompassing SQL query. E.g. you could read the field in the REST API and fetch the attachment via the media endpoint, or you could use `WP_Query` to export the data allowing you to use the standard API call for fetching a featured image, or grab the posts via SQL then loop through them in your language of choice to fetch the featured image in a second query. Or export to JSON in WP. This isn't the only/easiest/simplest/optimal way to do this

Comment: For example, if you load a post via the REST API, the JSON response contains the posts data, the featured image URL, as well as the featured images ID allowing you to grab more detail such as titles, filenames, alt data, EXIF data, you can do your import without writing a single line of SQL or PHP, and grab all the data and save it as JSON files for processing at a later date. That's completely ignoring using WP CLI to export the data in CSV/JSON/XML, separate SQL files, WXR files, or separate SQL queries. The way you're doing it is the hardest and most complex way of doing it.

Comment: e.g. https://tomjn.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1067 and its featured image at https://tomjn.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/1068, complete with alt text, mime types, dimensions, every size of image, who uploaded it, etc etc. These options all work even if this import is happening in realtime on user request in your new CMS, and there are many more options I haven't mentioned, too many for me to list, e.g. some people have written WP plugins that push the data to the new site, I've seen migrations happen in the background on cron jobs with pushing and pulling, countless ways to do it

Comment: I appreciate the alternatives you've described. If I don't get a SQL answer with the bounty I'll write something with code or use wp-cli.

Comment: @Anthony please consider that if you want, SQL could still be your _output_. You could write the PHP code needed to extract all the info, and write the SQL file as output, in the scheme the other CMS expects. That way you have a reusable backup without having to perform the exportation code again.